# Seeking Election Voting Data for Constituencies for Karnataka State Elections for 2013 and 2018

Tags: india, elections

I require data pertaining to the number of votes for each candidate in their specific constituency in the state of Karnataka for 2013 and 2018 elections.

I have surveyed the Indian Election Commision website, however, I cannot find anything for 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the below link for results of state and general elections:

http://lokdhaba.ashoka.edu.in/LokDhaba-Shiny/